# DevOps - Where to view dependency check report? E drive?

Tags: azure-devops, dependencies, owasp

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline step failing running the OWASP dependency check. I want to find what dependencies need to be updated.

The logs that are written during the dependency check pipeline step say:

```
[INFO] Writing report to: e:\vsts\a\7567\TestResults\dependency-check\dependency-check-report.html
```

I assume this `dependency-check-report.html` is where it will tell me what dependencies need to be updated. But I do not understand where this `e:\vsts\a\7567\TestResults\` location is, as this step is being run in DevOps. Is this somewhere in DevOps? I cannot seem to find it anywhere. "Download logs" on the pipeline page doesn't seem to have it either.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where this e:\vsts\a\7567\TestResults\ location is

When you run the pipeline in Azure DevOps, this path represents the local path of the machine where the agent locates.

In your case, the agent is self-hosted agent. You go to the local machine where the agent locates and find the dependency-check-report.html in  `e:\vsts\a\7567\TestResults\dependency-check`.

On the other hand, you can use the [Publish Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-pipeline-artifact-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) to upload the target file to Pipeline artifacts.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: dependency-check-build-task@6
  displayName: 'Dependency Check'
  inputs:
    projectName: test
    scanPath: test
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)'
    artifact: drop
```

**Note**: You need to set the `continueOnError: true` in OWASP dependency check task.

In this case, the dependency-check-report.html on agent machine will be uploaded to Azure Artifacts.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was being published as an artifact and I just didn't see where to  go to download it, but I found it :)